# Создать круг на карте с диаметром 90 % от ширины контейнера

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

Собственно сабж в вопросе.
размеры контейнера `map.container.getSize()`
центер - `map.getCenter()`
как на основе этих данных (или может нужны еще какие) построить окружность с диаметром 90% ширины контейнера?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper')
//if size = 300
//map.container.getSize()*90/100 == 270
let circle = document.createElement('div')
circle.style.width = '270px'
circle.style.height = '270px'
circle.style.position = 'absolute'
//map.getCenter() - 270/2 + Math.round(30/4) == 23
circle.style.left = '23px'
circle.style.top = '23px'
circle.style.border = '1px solid red'
circle.style.borderRadius = '50%'

wrapper.append(circle)
```

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper"></div>
```